# function that satisfies the majority of elements in haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell

I need to write a code that will give True if function satisfies the majority of elements of list and false in it does not satisfy.
for example: `moreThan odd [1,2,3]` is `True`, but `moreThan odd [1,2,3,4]` is `False`.
Here is my code:

```
moreThan funkt xs
   = let
      control funkt n (x : xs)
         = control (if .?. then n + 1 else n) xs
      contol funkt _
         = False
   in
   control funtk 0 xs
```

can somebody say how I can control that and what should I write in `.?.`
Thanks!

Comment: `moreThan = ((\(lTrue,lFalse) -> length lTrue > length lFalse).) . partition` would be somewhat more idiomatic.

Comment: Well, it'd be more idiomatic if you just used a `let` instead of throwing in a random pointless lambda.

Comment: Well, first, I have to ask: is this homework?  If so, it should be marked with the [homework] tag.

Comment: no, i have an elementary haskell exam and i am trying to prepare for it. So, i do not know how to solve this exercise and i'd be very happy if you could show how.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: What about the much sexier `(>>> uncurry (>) <<< length *** length) <<< partition`? :D

Comment: @Vitus and `length *** length` is much sexier `join (***) length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps not the most efficient solution, but certainly a very clear one, is as follows:

```
moreThan :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
moreThan f xs = length ts > length fs where
    ts = filter id bools
    fs = filter not bools
    bools = map f xs
```

Answer (score 3):

The function you wrote will return `False` for all arguments, since you invariably return `False` when the list ends.

The function you write need to keep track of two variables: The number of elements processed and the number of elements for which your predicate is true. Since this code is probably homework, I give you a construct that you can use to write the function. Fill in your own code at the `-- ???` places.

```
moreThan :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
moreThan pred = go 0 0 where
  -- procd: number of elements processed
  -- holds: number of elements for which pred holds
  go procd holds (x:xs) = go procd' holds' xs where
     procd' = -- ???
     holds' = -- ???
  go procd holds []     = -- ???
```

If you need more hints, feel free to leave a comment.

---

A more idiomatic way to write this function is using a fold:

```
moreThan pred = finalize . foldr go (0,0) where
  -- process one element of the input, produce another tuple
  go (procd,holds) x = -- ???
  -- produce a boolean value from the result-tuple
  finalize (procd,holds) = -- ???
```

Comment: `foldr` is a bad choice for this kind of problem. And you need only keep track of one thing, the difference of counts. `(> 0) . foldl' (\n x -> if p x then n+1 else n-1) 0` is what I'd find idiomatic.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer on what way is foldr uniodeomatic? The ideavwith the single counter is good.

Comment: I'm not saying `foldr` is unidiomatic (especially not in general), it's just the wrong idiom for the problem at hand. The update function is strict in both arguments, the result is independent of the order in which the list elements are processed, a clear case for `foldl'`.

Answer (score 2):

Know your libraries!

```
import Data.List(partition)
import Data.Function(on)

moreThan f = (uncurry $ on (>) length) . partition f
```

If you are not allowed to use partition, write it yourself:

```
part f xs = (filter f xs, filter (not.f) xs)
```

Or go the numeric way:

```
moreThan f xs = 2*s > length xs where s = sum $ map (fromEnum.f) xs
```

Answer (score 1):

```
majority :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
majority p = (0 <) . sum . map (\x -> if pred x then 1 else -1)
```

That is map (if pred x then 1 else -1) over list elements, then sums list elements and looks if the result is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hope this is efficient (only traverses the list once) but still reasonably clear.

```
majority :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
majority pred = g . sum . map f
  where f x | pred x    = 1
            | otherwise = -1
        g y = 0 < y
```